# How do I mock an optional class in java?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, crud

I was mocking my crud app and I was trying to mock the update API. As findById() method belongs to Optional class, I can't find a way to mock it. Here is the code snippet.

```
@Mock
@Autowired
private UserRepository repo;

@Test
public void testUpdateUser() {
    Integer userId = 3;

    Optional<User> optionalUser = repo.findById(userId);

    User user = optionalUser.get();
    user.setFirstName("Paul");
    repo.save(user);

    User updatedUser = repo.findById(userId).get();
    Assertions.assertThat(updatedUser.getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Paul");
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to mock `Optional`? Mocks should be used for hard-to-replace or hard-to-fake objects. `Optional` is a quite simple class that you should not need to mock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional class is a final class, so you cannot mock this class with Mockito. You should use PowerMockito. I add below a sample code. Please try this.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Optional.class)
public class PowerMockitoExample {


    @Mock
    Optional<User> optionalMock;

    @Mock Repository repo;

    @Test
    public void testUpdateUser() {
    
      //edit your mock user
      User yourUserData = null;
      
      Mockito.when(repo.findById(Matchers.anyInt())).thenReturn(optionalMock);
      PowerMockito.when(optionalMock.get()).thenReturn(yourUserData);
    
      Integer userId = 3;

      Optional<User> optionalUser = repo.findById(userId);

      User user = optionalUser.get();
      user.setFirstName("Paul");
      repo.save(user);

      User updatedUser = repo.findById(userId).get();
      Assertions.assertThat(updatedUser.getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Paul");
}
```

}

Comment: Why not just `Mockito.when(repo.findById(Matchers.anyInt())).thenReturn(Optional.of(yourUserData))`? What do you gain by mocking `Optional` here?

Comment: You need a mock Optional object , not real one. Because you'll use PowerMockito.when with mock Optional object.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Mock
@Autowired
private UserRepository repo;
```

This part of your code can lead to confusion. The principle behind `mocking` is to create a `mock` objects that is used by the class you want to test.

Looks like you want to test your repository. To do that you can use [test slice](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-data-jpa-test/) with `@DataJpaTest`.

Then in your case, you don't need to mock the `optional`.

In case you want to test a `Service` class or another class that use your `UserRepository`, you will define a `mock` and your class will looks like this :

```
@Mock
private UserRepository repo;

@InjectMocks
private UserService service;

@Test
public void testUpdateUser() {

    when(repo.findById(anyInt()).get()).thenReturn(aNewInstanceOfUser());

    ...

}
```

For more [reading](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html).